# Okta With Flask Angular Application Deployed on Apache Returning a 404 error on Correct Login

Tags: python, angular, apache, flask, okta

I'm currently trying to use Okta with Flask Angular which is deployed on Apache. This is my application.wsgi file:

```
import sys
import logging
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/basicapp/backend')

from app import app as application
```

My app.py file is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from flask_cors import CORS
import config

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, static_url_path='')
CORS(app)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def root(path):
    return render_template('index.html') # Return index.html
```

And my virtual host configuration inside httpd.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess application user=apache group=apache threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask_app/application.wsgi

    ServerAdmin abc@xyz.com

    <Directory /var/www/flask_app>
        WSGIProcessGroup application
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    TimeOut 600
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run my code locally without deploying on Apache, the code works fine. I'm able to redirect to Okta, log myself in and then it redirects to the home page of the application on successful authentication. However, when I deploy on Apache, after logging myself in instead of redirecting to the home page of the application, it's throwing a 404 error. What could be the reason for this? Do I need to add rewrite rules inside my httpd.conf?

I tried adding the .htaccess file but that would redirect to index.html. Shouldn't I redirect through mod_rewrite with mod_wsgi?